# Transparency option gone from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, transparency

I ran an app which disabled transparency in Windows 8 then crashed out leaving my UI without trapsnarency on windows (but still transparent on the taskbar).

I tried restarting to resolve the issue but it didn't, I then went on [this site](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8146-transparency-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) and tried all the suggestions and found that the 'enable transparency 'option is not available in the colour location and 'enable transparent glass' option is not available in 'performance options'.

Any ideas how I can get transparency back?

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore?

Comment: There are no restore points, the program I ran was just an exe which wasn't installed....

Comment: I just tried a restore to a much earlier point and it didn't help at all :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the the following registry key, and make sure it is zero:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationOpaqueBlend

For more information, see [here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread11301.html).