# Transparency option gone from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, transparency

Something happened and now my transparency option from Windows 8.1 is gone.

I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/459958/transparency-option-gone-from-windows-8%20this) solution but for me it does nothing. After restart the value

> ColorizationOpaqueBlend

is still in the registry with 0 value but nothing changes and the transparency option in Personalisation\Colour and Appearance does not appear

Comment: Are you talking about Windows 7 style Aero glass transparency by chance?  Because the linked solution is for Windows 7 which explains the reason it doesn't work on Windows 8.

Comment: I want the top-border of the window, which holds the  minimize/close buttons to be semi-transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for Aero glass transparency, which doesn't exist any more on Windows 8.

There are methods to add Aero glass transparency to Windows 8.x.
However, they require modifications to Windows and are not recommended,
so you do them at your own risk, and better mind your backups first.
For obvious reasons I have no personal experience with this procedure.

For more information see this product : [Glass8](http://www.glass8.eu/).
A guide is available [here](http://www.glass8.eu/guide.html).

You can also have a look at
[Hidden Secret Trick to Enable / Activate “Aero Glass” in Windows 8 “Aero Lite” Theme](http://www.askvg.com/hidden-secret-trick-to-enable-activate-aero-glass-in-windows-8-aero-lite-theme/)
for Windows 8 only.

Comment: What do you mean it does not exist anymore in Windows 8.1 ? Did they disabled it in an update after release of 8.1? I think i had it enabled once.

Comment: They didn't *disable* it - Microsoft simply *removed* it, probably because it was too hard to do on tablets as well as useless for them. Desktop users that liked it were left, as always, adding it back in via third-party products (where possible).

Answer (score 0):

Check these links to activate transparancy. 
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-unlock-the-hidden-aero-lite-theme-in-windows-8-1/
and 
 **also Visit :** 
winaero.com/blog/aero-glass-for-windows-8-1-released-download-links-inside/

OR

> **Step 1:** First you need to select the option “Personalize” from the context menu of desktop by right clicking on the desktop.
>   **Step 2:** You will see four High Contrast themes where you have to select the “High Contrast White” for activation. Now you need to wait
>   for a while because the system is applying the settings. After that
>   the Window of personalize again appears on your screen where you need
>   to select the option “Color” below the Contrasts options.
>   **Step 4:** Now don’t select any option in “Color” menu. Just again right click to the desktop where you will see “Personalize” option
>   that should be selected.
>   **Step 5:** Now again you will see “Personalize” menu where you will see some Windows Default themes. You need to select one of them.
>   **Step 6:** Now return to the Window where you have launched “Color and Appearance” menu. Click the option “Save Changes” and close the
>   window.
>   **Step 7:** Open any window to see whether Aero Glass is working properly or not. Lo behold! It works awesome and you have successfully
>   enabled it within a few minutes by using a few mouse clicks as it has
>   been shown in the image below. Now you would be able to use the
>   crystal like transparent window borders in every menu you open on your
>   screen.
>
> **Turn on Aero Glass Transparency with Aero8Tuner in Windows 8.1**
>  Aero8Tuner is a free tool that allows you to enable aero glass effects
>   in Windows 8.1 in just one click.
>
> **Visit : www.mytechmell.com/how-to/enable-aero-glass-windows-81/**

And 
[Finally a Way to Enable Transparency in Windows 8 Without any Bug or Glitch](http://www.askvg.com/finally-a-way-to-enable-transparency-in-windows-8-without-any-bug-or-glitch/)